# App Service Logging of System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError calls

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an appservice(windows) .net core 3.1 using  System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError statements.  I am able to see the output in the visual studio debugger but can not see it in the streaming logs output of the app service.  I have tried two documentation ([doc 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) , [doc 2](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/08/31/AzMon-AppServiceAppLogs.html)) whose steps do not look coherent .  I found_logger.LogInformation  statements are working and output can be seen in console during local debugging and streaming logs of the app service.  I can not see any logs from the System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError statements that I have written.  I feel there is some gap in the documentation as I have tried this on a simple hello world application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try disabling AppServiceFileAuditLogs and only have AppServiceAppLogs enabled and confirm, I remember it worked for me.

Comment: Is storage to blob a must for the feature to work.  I tried querying - AppServiceAppLogs  and got no data in log analytics.  When I try  System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError  I am not seeing any output in the logstream tab of the app service.

Comment: Did you try this with a .net core api ?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet on .Net core API but will certainly recommend you to disable audit log and give it a try. No, blob storage is not mandatory. These logs are exposed by app service to analytics through azure monitor.